# What container is easiest for combining JPEGS and MP3s as video?

Tags: algorithm, video, mp3, jpeg, containers

So I have N (for example, 1000) JPEG frames and 10*N ( for example, 100) seconds of MP3 sound.  I need some container for joining them into one video file (at 10 frames/second) (popular containers like FLV or AVI or MOV are better). So what I need is an algorithm or code example of combining my data into some popular format. The code example should be in some language like C#, Java, ActionScript or PHP. The algorithm should be theoretically implementable with ActionScript or PHP.

Can any one, please help me with that?

Comment: This is where I'd say "SMIL", but too bad nothing common plays it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're more concerned about simplicity than anything else, [Motion JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) is probably what you want, combined with the MP3 in an AVI container.

Your best option is really, really to use an existing library to do the encoding, at least for the container, though - if you do it yourself, you're going to have to write a *lot* of code to handle things like interleaving video and audio, sync, etc etc.